# Only one install, then have to restart

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2008

So, I've had this problem for a while now.  I think it's why I'm unable to do windows update, through windows update.  I can sometimes download the hotfix, but that sometimes doesn't work either.

Anyway, whenever I reboot, then attempt to install something, I get this message;

***user SYSTEM has previously initiated an install for
product Visual studio 2008.
that user will need to run the install again before they can use that product.  Your current install will now continue.***

It then lets me install something, if I attempt to install anything else it says "an install is already in progress".

This happens every single time after reboot.

Any idea what I can do to resolve this?  I've reinstalled visual studio 2008 twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the installation needs to be completed by the SYSTEM user for whatever reason.  You could try launching the setup program as SYSTEM with [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) with the command:

```
psexec -sid D:\path\to\setup.exe
```

Finish the installation with the SYSTEM user then see if the problem persists.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2008 like two years ago though

Comment: Jack, with all due respect, give Stephen's suggestion a try.

Comment: @JackMarchetti Perhaps a hotfix or service pack triggered the problem. I can't imagine anything happening worse than it just not working.

Answer (score 1):

I was too lazy to reinstall Visual Studio again, with all the modifications and themes, so I do something like (to close Windows Install service)

```
taskkill /f /im msiexec.exe
```

from the command prompt everytime I get the error. And as you'll probably see, you'll have two processes killed (hence the conflict).